# How to use @reboot for crontab with delay

Tags: cron

In crontab, I can use @reboot to run a command after the system reboot.  Is there a way to do this with an delay, i.e. run a command after 10 minutes of reboot?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Use the following:

```
@reboot /bin/sleep 600 ; /path/to/your/your_program
```

This will suspend execution of the shell for 600 seconds, and then run `/path/to/your/your_program`. Depending on your `SHELL` used for cron commands, the command syntax might be different.